# how can i query complexType entity locally

Tags: breeze

i have  complex type entity based on imported function ,

i can call this entity from remote server normally without problem ,

but when i want to execute query locally on the same entity , am getting error

> findOrCreateEntityGroups (breeze.debug.js:14326)    at
>   proto.executeQueryLocally (breeze.debug.js:12981)

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Please show us the query that works remotely but not locally

Comment: return EntityQuery.from('GetTree_Result')
                .withParameters({ clientnum: 8000, concode: 43 })
                .using(this.manager).execute()
                .to$q(querysecc, self._queryFailed);

            function querysecc(data) {

                _areTreeLoaded(true);

                return getbypage();

            }

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely clear on your question, but ComplexTypes can **only** be queried as part of their parent entities.  ComplexTypes are not entities themselves, they are simply structured collections of properties that are themselves properties of some other entities.

Comment: take look on MetaData

Answer (score 0):

],
            "functionImport": {
                "name": "GetTree",
                "isComposable": "true",
                "returnType": "Collection(ORICODBModel.GetTree_Result)",
                "parameter": [
                    {
                        "name": "CLIENTNUM2",
                        "mode": "In",
                        "type": "Edm.Int32"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "CODECON",
                        "mode": "In",
                        "type": "Edm.Int32"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "complexType": {
            "name": "GetTree_Result",
            "property": [
                {
                    "type": "Edm.Int32",
                    "name": "clientnum",
                    "nullable": "true"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Edm.Int32",
                    "name": "con_code",
                    "nullable": "true"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Edm.Int32",
                    "name": "level",
                    "nullable": "true"
                }}

---